# Javascript Get index value of array by comparing string value to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am reading a textbox and trying to compare the value to array and get the index value, but for some reason I can not get past this `TypeError: ar[z] is undefined` error even though I can `console.log` it using numeric value on previous line.

```
   //get name from textbox
    var name= document.getElementById("name");
     var name= name.value;

     //remove everything before name
    var index = name.toString().split(":");
    var index = index[1];

    //get product data to array
    var ar = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($productlist) ?>' );
    var nameslist= [];
    var z = 0;


   //this gives out an value
console.log(ar[0]['product_name']);

 //push 10 names to one list
////HERE IS THE ERROR: typeError: ar[z] is undefined

    while(z < 10){
     nameslist.push(ar[z]['product_name']);

      z++;
      }

    //Get the index value of name that matched the one from textbox
    var a = nameslist.indexOf(index); 
    console.log(a);
```

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle replacing the PHP tag with its actual output?

Comment: yes or paste the value of console.log(ar)

Comment: Most probable cause is that you're trying to address an undefined index, meaning that your array is probably less than 10 items. Try `while(z < ar.length)` instead... By the way, it's generally considered a best practice to use a `for` loop when you know the number of iterations you'll have

Comment: Value of console.log(ar[0]['product_name']) is "Test product"

Comment: @Bartdude Thank you, Indeed there were less than 10 values. Thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
var l = ar.length <= 10 ? ar.length : 10;
while(z < l) {
    nameslist.push(ar[z]['product_name']);
    z++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use  a for

```
//get product data to array
var ar = [{'product_name':"P1"},{"product_name":"P2"}]
var nameslist = [];
var z = 0;

console.log(ar[0]['product_name']);

 //push 10 names to one list
////HERE IS THE ERROR: typeError: ar[z] is undefined

 for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
 {
    nameslist.push(ar[i]['product_name']) 
 }

console.log(nameslist);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done using Jquery.

```
if ($.inArray(value, myvalueArr) > -1) {
    alert($.inArray(value, myvalueArr);)                       
}
```

This will give you the index in array with which the value was matched